# Dynamic multidimensional Arrays (Lists?)

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, multidimensional-array

From Reading up online, I've seen most answers to solving dynamic arrays such as to use a list. I'm a bit confused how to perform list operations on a multidimensional array. Maybe if I can understand how to implement a piece of code such as below, I'd be able to grasp them better.

```
    public void class Class1(){
    string[,] array;

    public void ArrFunction()
    {
        array=new string[rand1,rand2];
        int rand1=SomeRandNum;
        int rand2=SomeRandNum2;
        for(int i=0; i<rand1; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<rand2; j++){
              array[i][j]=i*j;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By "dynamic" do you mean "variable size"?  What list operations specifically are you looking to use?

Comment: Yes, and I would guess the only list operation I'd use would be add.

Answer (score 0):

Your method would work fine, but you need to declare and initialize your `rand1` and `rand2` variables before using them, and access into your array correctly:

```
public void ArrFunction()
{
    int rand1=SomeRandNum;
    int rand2=SomeRandNum2;
    array=new string[rand1,rand2]; // Don't use these until they're set
    for(int i=0; i<rand1; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<rand2; j++){
          array[i, j]=i*j; // Use [i, j], not [i][j]
       }
    }
}
```

Also, you can't initialize an array to a string:

```
// This gets initialized in your method
string[,] array; // ="";
```

Comment: Note also that `array[i][j]` won't work, since it's a 2d array. It needs to be `array[i,j]`.

Comment: It wasn't fixed when I wrote the comment. :)

Comment: Wow, let me change my example. Sorry about that. Rand1 and Rand2 should not be known. Edit Nvm..

Comment: @user1819301 What do you mean by "should not be known"?  You can pass them into the method as parameters, if you want

Comment: As in the dimensions of the multidimensional array should change during running time. The size is not known before the declaration of the array.

Comment: @user1819301  In your example, the size is known when the method is called - via "SomeRandNum".  What, exactly, are you trying to do?  That would help us provide better help...

Comment: Also the dimensions of the arrays aren't always balanced for example. 

array[0][5] //Index 0 has 5 items
array[1][3] //Index 1 has 3 items
array[2][4] //Index 2 has 4 items

Comment: @user1819301 Ahh - in that case, you need a jagged array (`[][]`, not `[,]`).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx